# Access elementGroup names from xml to java

Tags: java, xml

I am new to xml, i have following information of different columns in xml file, this i have to use to create table in mysql database through java with the same column names. E.g if i have hundreds of column how i can access "ColumnName" information particularly some where in java that i can use this afterwards to create table through java with given parameters.

```
<tns:elementGroup name="ColumnName" value="A">
<tns:element name="key">false</tns:element>
<tns:element name="datatype">double</tns:element>
</tns:elementGroup>

<tns:elementGroup name="ColumnName" value="B">
<tns:element name="key">false</tns:element>
<tns:element name="datatype">double</tns:element>
</tns:elementGroup>

<tns:elementGroup name="ColumnName" value="C">
<tns:element name="key">false</tns:element>
<tns:element name="datatype">double</tns:element>
</tns:elementGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the usage of [DOM XML parser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/). You'll have to figure some of it out yourself, but the basic part regarding your XML example should look like this:

```
NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("tns:elementGroup");
for(Node node : nList) {
    String columnName = node.getAttribute("name");
    // Do something with the column name
}
```